# systemd unit fails with error "trailing garbage"

Tags: coreos, systemd

I have the following very strange error on my systemd output:

May 26 10:21:11 ip-10-30-2-251.ec2.internal systemd[1]: [/run/fleet/units/someservice.service:13] Trailing garbage, ignoring.
May 26 10:21:11 ip-10-30-2-251.ec2.internal systemd[1]: [/run/fleet/units/someservice.service:14] Missing '='.

This is caused when I run the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=SOMESERVICE
Requires=docker.service  
After=docker.service

[Service]
User=core
TimeoutSec=15m
RemainAfterExit=yes
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull micronginx
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull microphp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c ' \
    MACHINE=`cat /etc/machine-id`; \
    etcdctl get /service/someservice/machines/$MACHINE/version; \
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then \
        etcdctl set /service/someservice/machines/$MACHINE/version 0; \
    fi; \
    while true; \
    do \
        MACHINE_VERSION=$(etcdctl get /service/someservice/machines/$MACHINE/version); \
        SOMESERVICE_VERSION=$(etcdctl get /service/someservice/version); \
        if [ "$MACHINE_VERSION" != "$SOMESERVICE_VERSION" ]; then \
            echo "Versions are different so starting deployment of version $SOMESERVICE_VERSION \n"; \
            etcdctl get /service/someservice/config > /tmp/someservice-$SOMESERVICE_VERSION; \
            SOMESERVICE_BASE_PORT=5000; \
            PORT=`echo $SOMESERVICE_VERSION | cut -d\'.\' -f 2`; \
            SOMESERVICE_PORT=$((SOMESERVICE_BASE_PORT+PORT)); \
            /usr/bin/docker pull someservice:$SOMESERVICE_VERSION; \
            /usr/bin/docker create -v /var/www --name someservice_$SOMESERVICE_VERSION someservice:$SOMESERVICE_VERSION; \
            /usr/bin/docker run --rm --name microphp_someservice_$SOMESERVICE_VERSION --volumes-from someservice_$SOMESERVICE_VERSION --env-file /tmp/someservice-$SOMESERVICE_VERSION microphp & \
            /usr/bin/docker run -d --name micronginx_someservice_$SOMESERVICE_VERSION --volumes-from someservice_$SOMESERVICE_VERSION -p $SOMESERVICE_PORT:80 --link=microphp_someservice_$SOMESERVICE_VERSION:php-fpm micronginx; \
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then \
                echo "Setting machine version in etcd to $SOMESERVICE_VERSION"; \
                etcdctl set /service/someservice/machines/$MACHINE/version "$SOMESERVICE_VERSION"; \
                sleep 1; \
                echo "New machine version is visible in etcd as $(etcdctl get /service/someservice/machines/$MACHINE/version)"; \
            fi; \
            rm -f /tmp/someservice-$SOMESERVICE_VERSION; \
        fi; \
        echo "sleep for 10 seconds and recheck \n"; \
        sleep 10; \
    done; '

[X-Fleet]
Global=true
```

Any ideas why or how I can troubleshoot this error or what may be causing it?

-S.

Answer (score 4):

I think I heard somewhere that there is a maximum line length for a service. Have you tried putting that giant command in to a script and just exec'ing that script?    If that doesn't work, you could create several ExecPre statements and construct the script one section at a time. Then your Exec could run that script.  If you are using a cloud-config you could use the 'write_file' command to write your script to the target machine.

[github issue max length](https://github.com/coreos/fleet/issues/992)

2048 is the maximum length of a line (the backticks are consumed and your command is one giant line).